# Why Bitdefender shows using Amazon bot in Network Activity?

Tags: networking, security, resource-monitor

I recently installed Bitdefender (Free Edition) to run a check for antivirus/malware in my system (Windows 8). It's been only a couple of days since I installed Bitdefender. I was just goofing around with the Resource Monitor when I noticed this - [Screenshot of Resource Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzMJs.png), in which the process "vsserv.exe" (which is Bitdefender Security Service) is shown with the address "ec2-52-55-142-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and which I suspect is an Amazon bot (and I may be wrong).

So what is going here? I am worried needlessly?

P.S. - Also once in a while I am also getting the message "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests" while searching anything on Google. Are these things related?

P.S. - I am not sure if this is the right place to post this question. Also please let me know if I need to include more details.

Comment: Yes; Your worried for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitdefender is connecting to something one the domain amazonaws.com. This is the [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/) which is a service the gives for consumers servers running in the cloud. So it is nothing suspicious that Bitdefender should connect to such an address, they probably use the Amazon Web Services for some of their servers.

The Google "detected unusual traffic", if it appears frequently, I'd be somewhat worried about. But it is certainly not related to this.